# Target build settings in Project build settings in Xcode

Tags: xcodebuild

Can we set the build settings for different targets in the project build settings in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just select the target, get info, and change your build settings.  You can get-info on the project to set global settings, get-info on individual targets to make things more specific, and change configurations (debug/release/etc.) in both areas for build specific behaviors.

Comment: No no, i want to set the build settings for different targets in the project build settings, For eg: if i want to change the different product name for different targets, i don,t want go to each target and change the name, instead i want to do that work in project build settings at a time.

Comment: Read up on Xcode settings. The targets inherit their settings from the project, so just set project-wide settings as needed. You can inherit variables and modify them in the target if needed, e.g. inherit generic name and then add some further extension to the name to make it target-specific.